# How to make flex children have equal widths and at the same time not larger than its contents?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.firstChild {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

.lastChild {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="firstChild">A very loooooooooooooooooong link</a>
  <span>Work</span>
  <span class="lastChild">Other</span>
</div>
```

[**Complete fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/03rwdfL8/18/)

The Problem is: The first flex child (long link) element is larger than its content (because of flex-grow). So when the user click next to its text, it also activates the link.

We used flex-grow here in order to make 1. and 3. childs equally wide, so the 2. element can stand -almost- in the middle (since the flex childrens' width vary a lot). How can i achieve this without using flex-grow? Or in other words, how can i guarantee that, the link's width is equal to its text's width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use this.

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="firstChild">
<a href="#" class="">A very looooooooooooooooooooong link</a>
</div>
 
 <div>
   <span>Work</span>
 </div>
  <div class="lastChild">
   <span>Other</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it with an additional `span.firstChild`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.firstChild {
  flex:1;
  text-align:left;
}

.lastChild {
  flex:1;
  text-align:right;
}

/* for overview */
a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <span class="firstChild">
  <a href="#">A very loooooooooooooooooong link</a>
 </span>
 <span>Work</span>
 <span class="lastChild">Other</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you :) it was actually pretty simple. Danish won with 1 min. difference sorry :)

Comment: Heh, it is not a contest. Happy to be helpfull :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: start;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <a href="#" class="firstChild">A very looooooooooooooooooooong link</a>
 <div>
   <span>Work</span>
 </div>
  <div class="lastChild">
   <span>Other</span>
 </div>
</div>
```